# How to prevent duplicate EventEmitters when passing @Output to child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I  created a form component and separated the form actions buttons to a child component so I had to create two `EventEmitter` and it's handlers for the same action.

Is there a way I can pass the `onDiscard` event handler received in `FormComponent` directly to `FormActionsComponent` without create a new handler for it?

I would like to avoid write two event handlers and emit the event twice.

#### FormComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
        <form [formGroup]="nametagForm" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()">
            ...
            <app-form-actions (onDiscard)="handleDiscard()"></app-form-actions>
        </form>
    `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  @Output()
  onDiscard = new EventEmitter<void>()

  handleDiscard(): void { this.onDiscard.emit() }
}
```

#### FormActionsComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-actions',
  template: `
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button (click)="handleDiscard()" type="button">Discard</button>
            <button [disabled]="formControl.invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class FormActionsComponent implements OnInit {
  private formControl: FormGroup

  @Output()
  onDiscard = new EventEmitter<void>()

  constructor(private readonly rootFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formControl = this.rootFormGroup.control
  }

  handleDiscard(): void { this.onDiscard.emit() }
}
```

#### Some Parent Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: `
        <app-form ... (onDiscard)="handleDiscard()"></app-form>
    `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {    
  ...
  handleDiscard(): void { // do something ... }
}
```

Comment: You could dependency-inject `ParentComponent` into `FormActionsComponent` and have `FormActionsComponent` directly call `ParentComponent#handleDiscard`, if you're OK with having them tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a service to achieve this:

```js
// my-form.service.ts
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyFormService {
  private readonly _discarded$ = new Subject<void>();
  readonly discarded$ = this._discarded$.asObservable();

  discard() {
    this._discarded$.next();  
  }  
}
```

Now you can inject the service into whichever component that you see fit and subscribe to the `discard$` variable.

For example:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ParentComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  constructor(private readonly myFormService: MyFormService){}

  ngOnDestroy() { this.destroy$.next() }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myFormService.discarded$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe(() => {
       // Do work
    })
  }
}
```

Inside the `FormActionsComponent`:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class FormActionsComponent {
  constructor(private readonly myFormService: MyFormService) {}

  handleDiscard() { this.myFormService.discard(); }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution, but it exposes the `discard` action and the it observable to the whole application. I think `FormActionsComponent` should be the only entity to trigger discard action.

Comment: You can always limit the scope of the service. From the docs: [Component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)